# Get the width of word-wrapped text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a div whose text content is word wrapped.  I'd like to get the post-word-wrapped width of this text using Javascript and/or JQuery.  What would be the best way to go about this?

EDIT: To be clear, I'm using the div in a flexbox layout where its flex value is 0 and a max-width is applied.  For some reason, the div has applied additional trailing whitespace to it and I'm having trouble getting rid of it.

Comment: Note that you can't find the width of "text", as this depends on the font, size, weight, tracking, embedded elements, and so on. You want to find the width of the element containing the text, as shown in my answer.

Comment: Please provide an [actual test case](http://jsfiddle.net) if you want help with a specific problem.

Answer (score 1):

Get the width of the div, i.e.

```
var w = myDiv.offsetWidth;
```

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.offsetWidth

Comment: I've updated my question to reflect the issue I'm having and why I'm asking.

Comment: very nice but this link also tells that _offsetWidth is part of the MSIE's DHTML object model. offsetWidth is not part of any W3C specification or technical recommendation)_ ..so can we have any thing which is recommended by W3C

Comment: Fear not: all modern browsers support these so-called "DOM0" standards.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery:

```
var textWidth = $('div').width();
```